# Rules for taking complements of probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm seeing some examples in my book where they take complements of probabilities and say some probabilities are less/greater than or equal to others. I just wanted to clarify that I am understanding them correctly.

Consider the example

$P[|\hat{p} - p| \leq \epsilon] \geq 1 - \delta$

The book immediately "subtracts both sides from 1". My first question is, what's the purpose of this form in the first place, if all subsequent steps require the below form?

$1 - P[|\hat{p} - p| \leq \epsilon] \leq 1 - (1 - \delta)$

$P[|\hat{p} - p|  \gt \epsilon] \leq \delta$

I kind of have an understanding as to what is happening here. They just take the "opposite" of both sides, but what causes the sign change? I thought the only way the sign changes is if you divide both sides by a negative number.

They also claim that

$P(|\hat{p} - p| \gt \epsilon) \leq P(|\hat{p} - p| \geq \epsilon)$

I don't know how to start explaining the above statement is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question:

$$P[|\hat{p} - p| \leq \epsilon] \geq 1 - \delta$$

Multiply by $-1$:

$$-P[|\hat{p} - p| \leq \epsilon] \leq -(1 - \delta)$$

Add $1$:

$$1-P[|\hat{p} - p| \leq \epsilon] \leq 1-(1 - \delta)$$

which is equivalent to

$$1-P[|\hat{p} - p| \leq \epsilon] \leq \delta$$

Hence

$$P[|\hat{p} - p| > \epsilon] \leq \delta$$

For your second question:

It is due to

$|\hat{p}-p| > \epsilon \implies |\hat{p}-p| \geq \epsilon$.

In general, if $A \implies B$, then $P(A) \leq P(B)$

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, let $X= |\hat{p} - p|$. 
Assuming $P(X \leq \epsilon) \geq 1 - \delta$, we obtain 
$$
\delta \geq 1-P(X\leq \epsilon)
$$
by adding $\delta$ to both sides and subtracting $P(X\leq \epsilon)$ from both sides.

Since $P(X\leq \epsilon)+ P(X>\epsilon)=1$, we have 
$1-P(X\leq \epsilon)=P(X>\epsilon)$. 
We thus conclude that 
$$
\delta \geq P(X>\epsilon). 
$$
Finally, 
the inequality $P(X>\epsilon)\leq P(X\geq \epsilon)$ holds because: 
$$
\begin{align*}
P(X\geq \epsilon) &= P(X>\epsilon) + P(X=\epsilon) \\
&\geq P(X>\epsilon).  
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I like the way you explained $P(X \geq \epsilon) = P(X \gt \epsilon) + P(X = \epsilon)$